# Laravel broadcast()->toOthers() methods does not work, still getting duplicates (Laravel 8 / Pusher / Laravel Echo / VueJs 3

Tags: laravel, vue.js, pusher, laravel-echo

I am listenig for MessageSentEvent

```
 window.Echo.private("chat" + this.chat.id).listen(
        "MessageSentEvent",

        e => {
          var date = new Date().getTime();
          this.lastMessageDate = moment().to(date);
          this.lastMessage = e.message;
          console.log(e.message.sender.id, this.loggedInUser.id);
         // if (e.message.sender.id !== this.loggedInUser.id)
         this.chat.messages.push(e.message);
        }
      );
```

while I am using the toOthers-method in my controller

```
  broadcast(
                new MessageSentEvent(new MessageResource($message), $authUser)
            )->toOthers();
```

leading to duplicates for the one who sent the message

[duplicates for the sender](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QuW2r.png)

while the receiver just get the expected 1 message

[receiver as expected 1 message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i4rbA.png)

if using  the outcommented condition, it works fine.... but too me it does not feel clean.
I must have made a mistake somewhere. Why does the toOthers()-method not work and I need to write a condition?

Thx:)

Answer (score 1):

On your axios config try to add your connection socket id.
Try this if You use Echo and if You use pusher or any socket library run the function that return a scketId  :

```
window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Socket-Id'] = window.Echo.socketId();
```

Comment: Thx for your answer.  If doing like you said, I get:

Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/messages' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:8081' has been blocked by CORS policy: Request header field x-socket-id is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.

Comment: I faced the same problem in the past and I fixed It like this. debug socket id on your console .

Comment: Check your laravel cors midleware  to allow server accept 'X-Socket-Id' header.

Comment: Iam still getting the cors error. i have this in my cors-middleware:
$response->header(
            'Access-Control-Request-Headers',
            'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With, X-Socket-Id'
        );
        $response->header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
        return $response;

Comment: adding the line of code as u wrote, creates a strange error, so I tried: 
````
 var response = await axios.post(`http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/messages`, data, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
        'X-Socket-Id': window.Echo.socketId()

      },

    })

Comment: but didnt work either :(

Comment: Honestly It work for me without any issue . Check client side part may your browser or some plugins preventing you from sending some headers types as for security purpose.

Comment: ok, thx sir. I will try it out :)

Answer (score 0):

your event should use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;

explained [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/broadcasting#only-to-others)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).